# What are the best weapons for fighting The Destroyer?

Tags: terraria

I've just got into hard mode and I have full Mythril armour. Whenever I fight the destroyer I seem to not deal enough damage and die. Any suggestions for weapons to use against The Destroyer?

Answer (score 0):

according to this [Gamepedia page](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:The_Destroyer_strategies) here are some weapons that work well when fighting the destroyer:

Melee

- Nights edge
- spears (hit many body parts)
- YOYO's
- DOW OF POW

Ranged

- Daedalus Stormbow, Adamantite Repeater or Titanium Repeater with Jester's/Holy Arrows
- Mega shark
- shotgun

Magic

- Nimbus rod
- Diamond Staff
- Golden shower

This list does not exhaust weapons that are suitable for defeating the destroyer.